# MongoDB aggregation $group with mutually exclusive fields OR split / unwind documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with schema, with mutually exclusive fields:

```
{
  item_id: Number, //if this field is present in document
  a_item_id: Number, //then this both field doesn't exists and vice versa
  h_item_id: Number, //then this both field doesn't exists and vice versa
  quantity: Number,
  other_field: String
}
```

#### The problem:

> *I need to split documents via `aggregate` stage in such order, that every document which contains both `a_item_id` && `h_item_id` (twin) fields will become two separate documents (they should inherit their base fields)*

Also, the point is, that I can't just `$group` by two fields at the same time, and then `$unwind` because, if this fields are presented in a document they always have different values between each other, like:

```
a_item_id: 2
h_item_id: 3
```

So, if `item_id` isn't present in document, then `a_item_id` and `h_item_id` are presented at the same time, always. **AND** they have different values between each other.

MongoPlayground [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9m3XxW9aWKx)

Does anyone have any idea to split this twins and achieve such results? Like this:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "item_id": 1,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "a_item_id": 2,
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "h_item_id": 3,
    "quantity": 1
  }
```

P.S. I understand that using this schema is a total failure, but I haven't project it. So I cann't re-build the collection in my own image.

#### *UPDATED:* What have I done already?

I am trying to solve my problem, by adding new array and push every value from every document to it, for later `$unwind`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      items_array: [
        "$item_id",
        "$h_item_id",
        "$a_item_id"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can just use JavaScript to update existing document _and then_ insert a new document for the condition `{ a_item_id: { $exists: true},  h_item_id: { $exists: true} }`, for each document - it is much simpler.

Comment: @prasad_. the point is: `need to split documents via aggregate stage` it's part of huge aggregation-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aggregation uses another approach, using `$facet` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { 
      $match: { a_item_id: { $exists: true },  h_item_id: { $exists: true } } 
  },
  { 
      $facet: {
          doc_a_item: [ 
               { $addFields: { h_item_id: "$$REMOVE" } },
          ],
          doc_h_item: [
               { $addFields: { a_item_id: "$$REMOVE" } }
          ]
       } 
  },
  { 
      $project: { doc: { $concatArrays: [ "$doc_a_item", "$doc_h_item" ] } } 
  },
  { 
      $unwind: "$doc" 
  },
  { 
      $replaceWith: "$doc" 
  }
] )
```

The ***output***, as two documents:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f1ed8090fdddd9a43c261e5"),
        "a_item_id" : 34,
        "quantity" : 50
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f1ed8090fdddd9a43c261e5"),
        "h_item_id" : 56,
        "quantity" : 50
}
```

The ***input*** document:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId("5f1ed8090fdddd9a43c261e5"), 
    a_item_id: 34, 
    h_item_id: 56, 
    quantity: 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

«Fine, I'll do it myself»

MongoPlayground [example for future uses](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TugJx1DXfE3)

```
Model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          a_item_id: 2,
          
        },
        {
          h_item_id: 3,
          
        },
        {
          item_id: 1,
          
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      item_id: {
        $filter: {
          input: [
            "$item_id",
            "$h_item_id",
            "$a_item_id"
          ],
          as: "d",
          cond: {
            $ne: [
              "$$d",
              null
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "a_item_id",
      "h_item_id",
      
    ]
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$item_id",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item_id"
    }
  }
])
```

At last group I could add:

```
  data: {
    $push: "$$ROOT"
  }
```

and then `$unwind` data field and receive the original documents.

Comment: Just some thoughts. Using the `$facet` stage is also possible to split the document.  Also, you could use `$$REMOVE` to unset a field.

Comment: @prasad_Thank you, for advice, I have seen `$facet` in MongoDB documentation before. I also though of using `$project` stage, instead of `$addFields` and `$unset` stages.